# MYSQL ERROR 1045 (20000) create a user

Tags: mysql, sql-grant, mysql-error-1045

When a tryd to create a user on MySQL with this command:

```
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 3tb_blumenau@'186.250.186.175'identified by '0f&k3' with grant option;
```

returns this error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES).

I tried to give all the permissions to user root, but the error still occurring.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you use flush privileges (root should have all privileges anyway but you know)

Comment: I think this means that you are using the wrong password

Comment: the password of root is correct. Because to acesses the mysql, I use the folowing comand:

mysql -u root -pmfs80

and then it's work.

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Are you accessing a database that is on your local machine?

Comment: yes, from the localhost

Comment: Have you recently upgraded?

Comment: Also what operating system are you using?

Comment: yes, recently i change the version of 5.1 to 5.6.
The O.S is WIndows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Comment: Can you tell us whether the below answer worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have updated your mysql version and not ran upgrade so as to fix your tables (for consistency with the version)
Okay so open your shell and make sure you are using a root user, now run the command "mysql_upgrade"
If this does not work then try running "C:\MySQL Server 5.6\bin> mysql_upgrade"
Good luck.

P.S. REMEMBER TO RUN AN UPGRADE WHENEVER YOU UPDATE VERSION -- very important :)

Comment: Thank you seanyt123. I will do that.